# Is there a way to get a string representation of ancestors with QueryPath or DOM?

Tags: php, xml, querypath

Something like:

```
find node: qp( $doc, 'UniqueSubNode' );

string representation: Root>Node>InnerNode>UniqueSubNode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QP parents() will get you all the ancestors, then all you need to do is html() each of them, I hope it helps.

Refer to this: http://api.querypath.org/docs/class_query_path.html#aae3c29dfc81839c3c054e7d608facd76

Comment: In the end I used the `$qp->parents()`, within the matches I find the specific parent node I need and/or I could have also looped the matches and created the node text representation using `$qp->tag()`

Comment: glad to see you solved it with qp, it's one of the best solutions I used for dom retrieval/manipulation in php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your server allows you to use it you could use the DOMDocument object.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

The DOMDocument object works in a fairly similar method to javascript's DOM manipulations. The text value is stored in the object's textContent member.